# checking two last elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing my calculator and want prevent div to zero. I guess I must check last to elements if they are "/0"? what I'm doing wrong?

```
 function div(input) 
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("t");
        var lastElement = (input.value.length-1);

        //alert(input.value[lastElement-1]);
        //alert(input.value[lastElement]);


        if (input.value[lastElement-1] === "/")
            { 
                if (input.value[lastElement] === "0")
                { 
                alert(" / to Zero");
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please, add some more information like HTML markup, rest of JS code, etc

Comment: Assuming your string really ends with `/0` and not `/ 0` or `/    0` or `/ 0 ` (space at the end), you're not doing anything wrong (though you have other options). But it's not how I'd approach it. I'd parse the equation -- presumably you will need to anyway? -- and *then* check whether the divisor is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx instead:

```
var is_div_by_zero = /\/[\s.0]+$/.test(value); // Returns true if it is divided by zero, false if otherwise
```

It matches:

- / 0
- /0
- /   0
- /  000
- / 0.00000
- etc.

As T.J. Crowder commented it is probably due to inconsistent formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to work *with* the Javascript engine instead of going *against* it.

Just evaluate the entered formula and handle the exceptions thrown by the Javascript engine.

Place your evaluation code inside a `try ... catch(e)` block and handle the exceptions there.

```
try {
    // your calculation code here, eg: 
    result = value1 / value2;
} catch (e) {
    // this catches the error and provides the proper way of handling the errors, 
    // and your script doesn't die because of the error
    // also, the e parameter contains the exception thrown, which provides info you can 
    // display 
    // or based on the error type come up with a proper solution
    alert (e.message);
}
```

More info on Javascript error handling: http://javascript.info/tutorial/exceptions

**Update**

**Forgot that, unfortunately, a division by zero does not result in an exception being thrown in Javascript**. It will result in `NaN` for 0/0 and `Infinity` for `x/0` (where `x` is any number). `Infinity` has the type `number`.

You can test for this after evaluating your equation.

Comment: This would only work if he/she parsed the string into two values and was certain that it is division, at which point one could just check if `value2 == 0`.  Try...catch would catch all errors, including unknown/unexpected ones (and is slower).

Comment: The idea is, to catch all errors and handle them one by one. You can always write different handling methods for different errors. This is a simple calculator which doesn't have to execute a lot of stuff in loops, so performance is not a show stopper here.

Comment: Dividing by zero is not an exception in JavaScript.

Comment: That's true, completely forgot that. Will update my answer.

Comment: An exception would probably be better, but sadly this is JavaScript, where 0/0 is NaN and 1/0 is Infinity...

Comment: Well, I wonder, who's great idea was this :) Every other programming language I know, throws an exception for division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer is one solution to your problem, but may bee too complicated for what would you like to achieve.

Instead of taking things from your input character by character, split your string on the operator and trim the parts. I will create the solution for two operands, and you can start from that.

```
var equation = document.getElementById("t").value;
var operands = equation.split('/');
var divisor = operands[operands.length - 1].trim();

// since the contents of your input are a string, the resulting element is also a string
if (parseFloat(divisor) == 0) {
    alert("Division by zero");
}
```

This is a very rough approach, as you will have to validate and filter your input (no other things than numbers and valid operators should be allowed). Also, you will have to check for operation priority (do you allow multiple operators in your equation?) etc.